# Patio Roof Cover - Will This Hold Up To Code & Be Strong

Tags: roof, patio, beam

My first time posting.  I plan on building a patio roof in my back yard.  It will have a metal roof on top.  Is this plan, span, strong enough and to code.  I'm located near Charleston, South Carolina (so no snow).  Please let me know if more information is required, and I'll do my best to add it to the post.  The rafters are 16' Long, with a 6 degree slope/pitch.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How are the posts attached to the slab? How is the attachment to the house made?

Comment: I plan on putting a 2X8 Ledger attached to my house.  I'm not sure the exact hardware to fasten the posts to the concrete, but I just added the type of faster that I think I'll need to my opening post.

Comment: Consult an engineer in your area, and/or go to the planning authority for the codes.

Comment: i would worry about how that design fails when a hurricane comes through. It will fail, but try to make it graceful.